# Sqlite like query not working

Tags: sqlite, join, left-join

It is a simple query,

```
SELECT fcellid,address FROM dd left JOIN r166 ON cgi like '%'+fcellid;
```

where dd is a view with this statement

```
select distinct fcellid from cdrData where cdrid=67;
```

and r166 is a view with

```
select * from cellIDData where cid in (58);
```

now when i run an individual query

```
select * from r166 where cgi like "%3505257008";
```

it returns correct result, but the join query is not returning any adresses.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have picked the wrong operator for concatenation, changing that would give you:

```
SELECT fcellid,address FROM dd left JOIN r166 ON cgi like '%'||fcellid;
```

This would be much closer to the working hardcoded version you specified

```
select * from r166 where cgi like "%3505257008";
```

Without a MCVE, you will have to test yourself.